# Best Practice: adding metadata to a modern SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, modern-experience

I'm curious to know if there is a best practice way of adding metadata to a SharePoint Online modern Team Site or Communication Site?

From my readings on the internet there seems to be a few ways of achieving this, to ensure that you receive desirable search results in modern search, and they include:

1. Add metadata to the Site homepage by adding columns to the "Site Pages" library
2. Create a custom content type on the site and add metadata to that content type (e.g. a hidden list for example)
3. Property Bag - add the metadata to the property bag of the site (seems to be only possible via CSOM or SP Designer).

From my initial tests, option 1, seems to work fine, but before I embark on a journey of bulk adding metadata to lots and lots of sites, I wanted to check is there a best practice way going forward with modern experiences and SharePoint Online?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create that custom Page ContentType in the global ContentType Hub and Publish it to all sitecollections. Not per single site library as you have to repeat yourself every new site.
Create only the Homepage that way, so each site has one set of metadata.
Stay away from property bags